# How can I install python3-dev for armhf using debian multiarch

Tags: python, multiarch

I have been going in circles trying to install this package as it is a dependency I need for something else (`libboost-all-dev:armhf`).

I have added `armhf` architecture and installed `python3:armhf` just fine. However, whenever I try to install `python3-dev:armhf`, it says it needs `python3-distutils:armhf`. When I try to install `python3-distutils:armhf`, it says

> Note, selecting 'python3-distutils' instead of 'python3-distutils:armhf'

This uninstalls `python3:armhf` and installs `python3:amd64` and its dependencies instead, and this obviously conflicts with `python3:armhf`. How can I resolve this?

I have found these two somewhat related questions, but the answers don't seem to actually resolve the issue:

[Debian multiarch: unable to install python for both armhf and amd64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42332023/debian-multiarch-unable-to-install-python-for-both-armhf-and-amd64)

https://superuser.com/questions/1439855/how-to-install-armhf-packages-on-an-x86-host

Comment: Since this question is more about linux package management than programming, you may get better support by asking on [Unix & Linux SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) or [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) one of the other linux sites.